# SSRS issues with Paramaters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to get a user prompt working for and ssrs report. I wanted to keep it simple, the user would just need to select how many days they wish to go back.

The script looks like this without the prompt and it works.
[Working script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phQdF.png)

when I change the highlighted 1 into @days to put in a userprompt and type in 1. I get no results, is there a reason why what I am doing does not work?

[What I want it to do but doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfWBP.png)

Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: What is the error it is giving you?

Comment: Hi, Sorry I forgot to mention that, it returns no results. I expect the same results as the first image.

Comment: What if you change the datatype from auto to int?

Comment: I thought there should be a way to do that, when I click the dropdown however, it only shows auto or text. It doesnt give me an option to choose anything else.

Comment: Try casting to an integer value in your query.... `SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, CAST(@Date AS Unsigned))`

Comment: Hi BJones, I tried that exact line but it still did not return anything.

Comment: I forgot to add, I am using an ODBC connection to a MYSQL server for the script.